# Classic ASP - Request object Is Empty

Tags: iis, asp-classic, vbscript

I'm working on adding a feature to an old classic asp site and ran into an interesting problem.  The following line on the page results in the helpful error "Object required:'' "

```
strServerName = Request.ServerVariables("server_name")
```

When I attached a debugger to look at it, Request is in fact Empty, which I don't understand how that can happen?  This line exists on several pages and executes with no problems besides this one.  In this case, the page is executed by a Redirect from another page.

I've been searching for a solution for a day or so now and haven't been able to locate anything that's been helpful.  I'm desperate, any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Oh, and if any more information is required, please don't hesitate to call me out.

Thanks!

**Update 1**
As requested, below is the entire code snippet wrapped in <% %> tags.  This block exists as first code within the file (named 'order-results-instant.asp'):

```
<%
strServerName = Request.ServerVariables("server_name")
strServerName = UCase(strServerName)

strServerURL = "http://localhost/cbr"
strServerURLhttps = "https://localhost/cbr"
strConnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=CBR; Integrated Security=SSPI"

Dim objConn
Dim sql_stmt
Dim rs  
%>
```

**Update 2**
I've used the following 2 methods to redirect execution to this page - perhaps this can cause the request to be lost?

```
 'Response.Redirect strServerURL & "/order-results-instant.asp?gwstep=1"
 Response.Write "<META HTTP-EQUIV=""refresh"" content=""5;URL=" & strServerURL & "/order-results-instant.asp?gwstep=1"">"
```

Comment: Please post the code from the page (including <% %> header) and provide the full filename of the page.

Comment: I agree with OrbMan, this code works if I have just a basic ASP page with nothing else in it. Can you provide more details on your code? It is possible an external variable is causing this.

Comment: The page is loaded by redirecting from a source page first.  I have tried this redirect using the following 2 methods - perhaps this will shed some light?  (My apologies, it's just been a long time since working with asp, and even then I don't have a lot of experience).

    'Response.Redirect strServerURL & "/order-results-instant.asp?gwstep=1"
    Response.Write "<META HTTP-EQUIV=""refresh"" content=""5;URL=" & strServerURL & "/order-results-instant.asp?gwstep=1"">"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scan through the rest of the code.  At the Global level you will find this:-

```
Dim Request
```

Rename this variable and its current usage and the Request object attached to the script context will become visible.

Comment: You sir are a genius!!!  I feel completely and totally dumb now, but I thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

On your server is the Active Server Pages Web Service extension allowed (turned on) ?

Comment: Yes, and other asp files execute with no problem (even when accessing the Request object).

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code into my test asp file with the following code and it redirected just fine.

```
<%
strServerName = Request.ServerVariables("server_name")
strServerName = UCase(strServerName)
strServerURL = "http://localhost/"
strServerURLhttps = "https://localhost/"
strConnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=CBR; Integrated Security=SSPI"
Dim objConn
Dim sql_stmt
Dim rs  

Response.Write(strServerName)

if Request.Querystring("test") <> "1" then
    Response.Redirect("http://" + strServerName + "/asptest.asp?test=1")
 end if
%>
```

The only real difference is I am adding "http://" to the redirect. Maybe something I did will shed some light to help you solve  your issue.

thanks

Comment: I also was able to take your sample page and get it to run with no problem and had access to the Request object (as I do with other pages in this same site).  But I still have the same problem with a Empty request after the redirect.  I also checked to ensure that I was using a fully qualified url, and I was in fact doing so, and it seemed to make no difference to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you try to access it at an earlier point in the page?

Comment: Acutally, this is the absolute first line of executed code that is failing.  I have moved it to a later point in the page and it results in the same error.